# Splitting TempDB into multiples files equal to number of CPUs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, storage, tempdb, disk-structures

The article [SQL Server tempdb Best Practices Increase Performance](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/SQL-Server-tempdb-best-practices-increase-performance) suggests that I should split `tempdb` into a number of files equal to the number of cores. So for 4 cores you get 4 files.

> By having the larger number of files, you can increase the number of
>   physical I/O operations that SQL Server can push to the disk at any
>   one time. The more I/O that SQL Server can push down to the disk
>   level, the faster the database will run. With standard databases, SQL
>   Server can cache a large amount of the data that it needs into memory.
>   Because of the high-write nature of the tempdb, the data needs to be
>   written to the disk before it can be cached back up into memory.

Though it sounds good in theory, is it really that good as a general optimisation? Is it something that may only apply for specific systems where IO is very high?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A ratio of 1/4 to 1/2 times the number of TempDB data files to machine cores has long been the recommendation...

> But there's now even better guidance. At PASS in 2011, my good friend Bob Ward, who’s the top guy in SQL
>   Product Support, espoused a new formula: if you have less than 8
>   cores, use #files = #cores. If you have more than 8 cores, use 8 files
>   and if you’re seeing in-memory contention, add 4 more files at a time. [[link]](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-1230-tempdb-should-always-have-one-data-file-per-processor-core/)

The last sentence has always been relevant. If you're not seeing contention, why add additional files? To play safe, most will add 2-4 files as a starting point for the majority of builds but beyond that, measure and react.

Answer (score 10):

Like most **general** guidelines, it is a an oversimplification in its most positive light.  At best, **it is a good starting point** (provided you don't aren't keeping the 1:1 *core:data file* ratio with a large amount of cores).

There is no replacement for proper design ***and proper follow-up monitoring and baselining***.  The reason behind having multiple data files for *tempdb* is to reduce and mitigate allocation page contention.  There are numerous published posts on how to monitor this contention and take action accordingly.  Below are a few resources:

[Breaking Down TempDB Contention (Part 1)](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/breakingdowntempdbcontention)
[Breaking Down TempDB Contention (Part 2)](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/breakingdowntempdbcontentionpart2)
[Analyzing Tempdb Contention](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/21/analyzing-tempdb-contention-a-month-of-activity-monitoring-part-21-of-30.aspx)
[Optimizing tempdb configuration with SQL Server 2012 Extended Events](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/optimizing-tempdb-configuration-with-sql-server-2012-extended-events/)

But to answer your question, no this isn't a hard-and-fast configure-and-forget part of *tempdb*.